# How can I complete "Siege on the Dragon Cult" when I killed Captain Valmir's impostor before the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, when I first arrived at Forelhost, there was this Imperial alone by his firecamp. I tried to enter Forelhost, but the door was locked and absolutely needed a key. I talked to the Imperial camping just by the door but he didn't mention Forelhost.

I tried to pick-pocket the Imperial, hoping that he had the key and saw that note that tells that he is an impostor! Then he got mad for the pick-pocket and tried to kill me, so I killed the false-Imperial.

I entered Forelhost, crawled the dungeon, learned its gruesome story and picked up the great unique item at the end. Suprise! A new quest appears: "Siege on the Dragon Cult" with that objective: Return to Captain Valmir.

I got outside via the balcony and saw an Imperial standing beside the impostor's body. I said to myself: "Hey! Here's the real Captain Valmir! Time to tick that quest!". To my great surprise, as soon as I got near he attacked and I had to kill him in a fiery burst of flames.

But now the quest "Siege on the Dragon Cult" stays there, waiting for me to return to the Captain Valmir that is now a roasted to a crisp by the door to Forelhost, not far from the body of the impostor.

How can I complete that quest? (I am using the PC version of Skyrim and can use the console if needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this unofficial source](http://skyrim.gamepedia.com/Siege_on_the_Dragon_Cult)

> - If Captain Valmir is already dead, the objective assigned will be to find the key to the well in the Catacombs.
> - If Captain Valmir is still alive, then the objective assigned is to return to him with the mask.

This can indicate a bugged quest, so here's 3 possible solutions:

- If you did not already, retrieving the key from his body may progress the quest.
- Reloading to a previous save.
- If you're playing the PC version, you can use the console command `setStage dunForelhostQST 110` to progress to the next stage and complete the quest.

Comment: There was no key left to pick up so I used the console command.